# How to use a single agent for multiple jobs/stages in azure devops YAML pipeline

Tags: azure, tfs, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I am working on Azure DevOps YAML pipeline, I am not sure whether we can use single agents through out the pipeline.
I have multiple jobs/stages - Build, Deploy, Post-Deploy, and want to assing that to a single agent, because it is consuming same artifacts.
Is there a way to assign a single agents through the pipeline.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you talking about specifically using the same agent for each individual stage, same pool, or same agent throughout all the jobs in a given stage?

Comment: Yes I am talking about using same agent for multiple stages/jobs

Comment: @Abhishek Anvekar Not get your latest information, is the workaround helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 9):

Yes there is a way all you need to do is to store the agent name of yo first job in a variable and then for any other job you need to ask for same agent. Its done like this -

```
 jobs:
- job: A
  steps:
  - bash: |
     echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=AgentName;isoutput=true]$(Agent.Name)"
    name: passOutput
- job: B
  dependsOn: A
  variables:
    AgentName: $[ dependencies.A.outputs['passOutput.AgentName'] ]  
  pool:
    name: pool1
    demands: Agent.Name -equals $(AgentName)   
  steps:
  - bash: |
     echo $(AgentName)
```

Comment: This seems to work. The only issue with this is that you have to queue for that specific agent if some other jobs get in between.

Comment: The above is good for this scenario but if Job B needs to run irrespective of Job A, then this doesn't work as ADO will throw an error saying Job B cannot run when variable where we store the Agent.Name evaluates to empty. This could happen if they are multiple steps in Job A and something in it fails before the variable is loaded. And this will prevent Job B from running.

Comment: Anybody skilled enough with Azure's freaking GUI to make this happen?  I use self hosted agents and my code base is in SVN so I can't use YAML (Go Microsoft!! love y'all).  Struggling to figure out which GUI fields result in the above.

Comment: Does anyone know how to get the agent name with PowerShell instead of Bash? All my agents are Windows machines

Comment: But this is Egg and Chicken problem, No? Sharing an Agent name is also through output variable which was already not working because of multiple agents being picked up by parallel job or at the stage level?

Answer (score 6):

> I dont want the agent to do checkout operation everytime for new job

Using the checkout keyword to configure or suppress this behavior.

```
steps:
- checkout: none
```

You can refer to this official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#checkout) for details.

Comment: RTFQ OP doesn't want to break the pipeline they want to make the fetch unnecessary

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can define a specific agent on YAML.

E.g:
pool:
name: AgentPoolName
demands:
- agent.name -equals AgentName

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/demands?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Comment: Hi Thanks for your response, my question is bit different, I dont want the agent to do checkout operation everytime for new job.
Like my first job generates the artifacts, and the seconds should automatically have that artifacts in the agent folder.

Comment: This is the YML file:
trigger:

- Master

pool
:
  vmImage: Windows-2019

stages:
  - stage: Build
    displayName: "Build"
    jobs:
      - job: Build

        displayName: Build
        steps:
          - task: PowerShell@2
            inputs:
              targetType: 'inline'
              script: Write-Host "This is Build Job"
            
      - job: Deploy
        displayName: Deploy
        steps:
          - task: CmdLine@2
            inputs:
              script: echo This is Deploy job

Answer (score 4):

The quick answer. Only use [Steps as they are run sequentially](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runs?view=azure-devops#run-each-step) on the same agent.

If you use [MS hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#use-a-microsoft-hosted-agent) (e.g. windows-2022) it´s my experience that the pipeline spins up a new agent for each stage and job, so getting the same agent seems "impossible" in this scenario. I might be wrong.

Alternatively you can [Use Artifacts across stages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/pipeline-artifacts?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#use-artifacts-across-stages) and keep the option to parallelize open.

**At the end of your Build Stage/Job:**

*If needed. [Copy the files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/copy-files-v2?view=azure-pipelines&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) to the artifactstagingdirectory:*

```
- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    Contents: '**'
    TargetFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
```

Add a publish artifact that "Saves" your build result.

```
- publish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
  name: CheckoutAndBuildToPipelineArtifact
  displayName: 'Publish CheckoutAndBuildToPipelineArtifact'
  artifact: drop
```

**At the beginning of the next Stage/Job (Deploy):**

You would download the artifact result from the Build.

```
steps:
- checkout: none # Don´t check out repository. Might be redundant
- download: current # The artifact created in the current pipeline
  artifact: CheckoutAndBuildToPipelineArtifact
```

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot use a specif agent as @Savio Moreira suggested the only option that I found is to duplicate some steps.

In my case have a similar pipeline with 2 stage:

- Build (To validate PR)

  - Visual Studio build
  - Visual Studio Test
  - VS test
- Publish (To publish the Artifact after merge into master)

  - Visual Studio build
  - Copy file
  - Publish build artifacts

The Build part is trigger only when a PR is created using a condition in the YAML Stage and Enable Branch policies.
The Publish part is trigger only when there is merge into master.

It's a bit annoying that some steps need to be duplicated but the execution is unique, and with the same pipeline I can execute validation before merge and then create the artifact once the code is into master.

The checkout option doesn't help since in my case each stage is executed on a completely different container.